# Странности Eclipse/CDT (Linux)

Tags: c, eclipse

Version: Luna SR2 (4.4.2), Build id: M20150204-1700

Собственно, всё на картинках.

[image: Eclipse/CDT]

[image: Eclipse/CDT]

При этом:

1. Сборка проекта проходит без единой ошибки, то есть это глюк именно парсера Eclipse.
2. В других местах кода никаких замечаний по поводу `va_arg` и прочих `va_*` у него нет.

Чего только не пробовал, даже отключил вообще все валидаторы в настройках C/C++, не помогает.

Можно ли побороть?

Comment: Попробуйте скачать последнюю версию eclipse и посмотреть, вдруг в ней заработает. Если же нет, попробуйте сбросить настройки.

Comment: Это и есть самая последняя :) Сейчас одну штуку проверю ещё.

Comment: Щас сам вариант ответа дам.

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то ему не нравится звёздочка. Ни так:

```
va_arg( ap, char * );
```

Ни так (в предположении, что он из-за пробела неправильно пытается раскрыть макрос):

```
va_arg( ap, char* );
```

Помогает следующий трюк:

```
typedef char * pchar;
va_arg( ap, pchar );
```

---

Казалось бы... Ан нет, и с другими типами глючит! Решение примерно такое же, было:

[image: Eclipse/CDT]

Стало:

[image: Eclipse/CDT]

Comment: Похоже, ключевые слова он там не ест.

Comment: Ага. А тайпдефы и переменные - нормально. Неожиданно...

Comment: typedef - это всего лишь имя. Да, имя типа. Но имя. А char и unsigned - это ключевые слова языка.

Comment: Так чем он парсит-то? Если компилятор/препроцессор, которые задействованы в среде,  нормально всё переваривают. Да и в `ман va_arg` явно указано, что второй аргумент - тип, и про звёздочку тоже явно всё расписано. Я так полагал, что оно задаётся в настройках валидаторов c/c++. Но если там всё поотключать и вырубить cppcheck, всё равно краснеет.